# How to prefix the number to a column which has data type "double-precision float [DT_R8]" in SSIS using "derived Column"

Tags: ssis-2012

I have a **commission** table which has the column `Invoice Number` with data type as `double-precision float [DT_R8]`.

I want to prefix the number **71** to the `Invoice Number` column using **Derived Column** transformer in SSIS.

I tried writing expression like

```
"71" + [Invoice Number]
```

It showing the error message:

[image]

Can anyone help me solving this?